Configure current GNOME 47 to put buttons (back) at bottom
I use KDE on Fedora, and I'm used to modal dialogs to look like the following:

There is a server side window decoration, the modal dialog buttons are at the bottom. To me that makes sense, my reading direction is from top to bottom. Hence I read the title, I read the message, and then I read the actions that I can take.
There are a few GNOME/GTK programs that I use, like GIMP. And since the most recent update to GNOME 47, the GNOME design has changed yet again. Not only is there client side decoration (which I don't want) but they have moved the buttons to the top.

To me, this doesn't make any sense. I start reading at the top, read the bulk of the text and then have to go back up to find the correct buttons.
Even worse, as I have some Snap apps like Slack, these come with a different version where the buttons were still on the bottom:

Is there some option in GNOME/GTK to get these buttons back to the bottom?

(could you check the exact Gnome version you're running and add that to your question, that would help)

@MarcusMüller: It's GNOME 47.
